# How to effectively parse text files with Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I understand how to get specific data from a file with Java 8 Streams. For example if we need to get *Loaded package*s from a file like this

```
2015-01-06 11:33:03 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: eVentToRequestsBolt __ack_ack 
2015-01-06 11:33:03 c.s.p.d.PackagesProvider [INFO] ===---> Loaded package com.foo.bar
2015-01-06 11:33:04 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: eventToManageBolt:2, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-6722594615019711369 -1335723027906100557]
2015-01-06 11:33:04 c.s.p.d.PackagesProvider [INFO] ===---> Loaded package co.il.boo
2015-01-06 11:33:04 c.s.p.d.PackagesProvider [INFO] ===---> Loaded package dot.org.biz
```

we can do

```
List<String> packageList = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[1])).filter(line -> line.contains("===---> Loaded package"))
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .map(arr -> arr[arr.length - 1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I took (and slightly modified) the code from [Parsing File Example](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-stream-and-lambda).

But what if we also need to get all the dates (and times) for *Emitting:* events from the same log file? How we can do this within working with the same Stream?

I can only imagine using `collect(groupingBy(...))` which groups lines with *Loaded packages* and lines with *Emitting:* before parsing and then parse each group (a map entry) separately. But that would create a map with all the raw data from log file which is very memory consuming.

Is there a similar way to effectively extract multiple types of data from Java 8 Streams?

Comment: You can do this with peek(), however this is not generally recommended. In particular groupingBy will only produce a result once all the data has been processed.

Comment: Could you expand a bit? The data you posted does not contain "some" so I'm not sure I understand. Could you post a sample input / output of what you'd like?

Comment: @Tunaki Some is a wrong word. I corrected the question. I need to get all the Loaded packages from the file. They are in lines with arrows ===--->.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `pairing` collector which I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/4856258) and which is available in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. For your concrete problem you will also need a `filtering` collector which is available in JDK-9 early access builds and also in my StreamEx library. If you don't like using third-party library, you may copy it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631981/4856258) answer.

Also you will need to store everything into some data structure. I declared the `Data` class for this purpose:

```
class Data {
    List<String> packageDates;
    List<String> emittingDates;

    public Data(List<String> packageDates, List<String> emittingDates) {
        this.packageDates = packageDates;
        this.emittingDates = emittingDates;
    }
}
```

Putting everything together you can define a `parsingCollector`:

```
Collector<String, ?, List<String>> packageDatesCollector = 
    filtering(line -> line.contains("===---> Loaded package"),
        mapping(line -> line.substring(0, "XXXX-XX-XX".length()), toList()));

Collector<String, ?, List<String>> emittingDatesCollector = 
    filtering(line -> line.contains("Emitting"),
        mapping(line -> line.substring(0, "XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX".length()), toList()));

Collector<String, ?, Data> parsingCollector = pairing(
    packageDatesCollector, emittingDatesCollector, Data::new);
```

And use it like this:

```
Data data = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[1])).collect(parsingCollector);
```

Comment: That seems to be a more elegant solution if we have pairing and filtering already.

Answer (score 1):

You may solve it without defining new collectors and using third-party libraries in more imperative style. First you need to define a class which represents the parsing result. It should have two methods to accept an input line and combine with existing partial result:

```
class Data {
    List<String> packageDates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> emittingDates = new ArrayList<>();

    // Consume single input line
    void accept(String line) {
        if(line.contains("===---> Loaded package"))
            packageDates.add(line.substring(0, "XXXX-XX-XX".length()));
        if(line.contains("Emitting"))
            packageDates.add(line.substring(0, "XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX".length()));
    }

    // Combine two partial results
    void combine(Data other) {
        packageDates.addAll(other.packageDates);
        emittingDates.addAll(other.emittingDates);
    }
}
```

Now you can collect in quite straightforward way:

```
Data result = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[1]))
    .collect(Data::new, Data::accept, Data::combine);
```